# Embedded custom view not displaying

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a XIB based Cocoa OS X App.
In my main window I wish to draw one or more instances of a custom view.

My XIB file has the main window, and I dragged out a Custom View too. I have subclassed NSView and set the class type for the custom view to my new subclass (I called it ChannelControlsView).

I have dragged a Custom View onto the main winodw and set it's class type also to ChannelControlsView as you can see in the attached image.

[image]

However when my main window is drawn, the custom view does not appear. What mistake have I made?
This is pretty much how I do it on iOS and it works there, so I guess there are some extra steps for OS X apps?

Answer (score 0):

The view that appears at the bottom of the provided screenshot (with the controls on it) is not a part of the windows view hierarchy, this is why it isn't appearing when you load the window.

To make it a part of the hierarchy:

1. Select it using the Interface Builder dock (the part on the left-hand side of the screenshot),
2. Drag it (still in the dock) to just below *Mov View* and just above *Channel Controls View*.
3. Delete the *Channel Controls View* that is already on the window (the one colored pink in the above screenshot)

Your hierarchy should look the same `Window >> Mov View >> Channel Controls View`, but you shouldn't have any *floating* views (i.e. views on the canvas, but not on the Window).